# iPhone settings bundle, is there any way to change the font?

Tags: iphone, font-size, settings.bundle

I have in my settings.bundle a toggle switch, and the title property does not fit, because the text is too big, is there any way to reduce the font size, or have a line break?.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]
<sub>(source: [useyourloaf.com](http://useyourloaf.com/storage/post-images/2010-05-18-003.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1274208663573))</sub>

Note: This is actually not my app, but I am at work and imageshack is blocked so I cannot upload something. But basically my problem is that the text "Rotation Lock", is something larger for me and it does not fit causing it to look like "My very very long tex...."

Comment: Could you post a screenshot indicating what you mean? It'll make it easier to work out which text you mean.

Comment: @NicholasSmith Yes I just edited with a screenshot to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: @Oscar: out of curiosity: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. As per [Settings Application Schema Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Introduction/Introduction.html), a key allowing changes of font size is not available.

As a workaround, I'd suggest to shorten your label text so it fits available space and is still informative for the user.